# Image sizing not consistent in different browsers

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, image-size

I have an issue where my thumbnails get super weird sizes in Firefox (and maybe to some users in Chrome). For each of my mapped projects I display a thumbnail with the size of 240 x 220 px, but in Firefox they look like this:
[Screenshot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7fb8.jpg)

It should look like this:
[Screenshot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2vFg.jpg)

My code looks like this:

```
const StoryThumbnail = styled.img`
  width: 240px;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
  }
`;
```

And this:

```
    {projects &&
          projects.map((project) => {
            return (
              <StoryWrapper key={project.title}>
                <StoryThumbnail src={project.thumbnail.url} />
......
```

Got any ideas? I'm grateful for all thoughts and input.

PS. Feel free to check out how it looks in your browser and add screenie if you want. https://carolineborg.netlify.app/projects

Comment: Have you tried adding min-height and min-width with max-height and max-width attributes to see if that fixes the issue? Usually pairing them gives constant sizes.

Comment: @SpencerChurchill Yes, it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just setting `height` and `width`, set both min and max:

```css
const StoryThumbnail = styled.img`
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  min-height: 220px;
  max-height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    max-height: 350px;
  }
`;
```